# Android MPCharts x-axis wordwrap overlapping

Tags: android

I used the Charts library in iOS where a 'xAxis.wordWrapEnabled = true' is available to stop x-axis labels from overlapping over each other.

The same option does not seem to be available on Android for x-axis values. (Only available for Legend)

Any ideas of how I can stop x-axis labels from overlapping in Android MPChart library please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can custom your XAxis like code below.It will be automatically broken down your lengthy strings to next line avoid overlapping.

Set offset for drawing multiple lines

`chart.getXAxis().setYOffset(12);
chart.setXAxisRenderer(new MyXAxisRenderer(chart.getViewPortHandler(),chart.getXAxis(),chart.getTransformer(YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT), labelCount));`

```
public class MyXAxisRenderer extends XAxisRenderer {
private int labelCount;

public MyXAxisRenderer(ViewPortHandler viewPortHandler, XAxis xAxis, Transformer trans,
                        int labelCount) {
    super(viewPortHandler, xAxis, trans);
    this.labelCount= labelCount;
}

@Override
protected void drawLabel(Canvas c, String formattedLabel, float x, float y, MPPointF anchor, float angleDegrees) {
    int offset = 24;
    float widthUnit = mViewPortHandler.contentWidth() / labelCount - offset;
    Rect rect = new Rect();
    int labelFittingLength = formattedLabel.length();
    mAxisLabelPaint.getTextBounds(formattedLabel, 0, labelFittingLength, rect);
    while (rect.width() > widthUnit) {
        labelFittingLength--;
        mAxisLabelPaint.getTextBounds(formattedLabel, 0, labelFittingLength, rect);
    }
    // space 5dp from XAxis
    float yPreviousLine = y - mXAxis.getYOffset() + 15;
    if (labelFittingLength == formattedLabel.length()) {
        super.drawLabel(c, formattedLabel, x, yPreviousLine, anchor, angleDegrees);
    } else {
        int spaceMultipleLine = 8;
        List<String> subLabels = splitByNumber(formattedLabel, labelFittingLength);
        for (String subLabel : subLabels) {
            Utils.drawXAxisValue(c, subLabel, x, yPreviousLine, mAxisLabelPaint, anchor, angleDegrees);
            yPreviousLine = yPreviousLine + rect.height() + spaceMultipleLine;
        }
    }

}

private List<String> splitByNumber(String s, int size) {
    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    int index = 0;
    while (index < s.length()) {
        strings.add(s.substring(index, Math.min(index + size, s.length())));
        index += size;
    }
    return strings;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I will try it out :)

Comment: Hi man, thanks for this! It works (finally found some time to try it out) I have a follow-up question, I'm trying to get this to update when the chart is scaled. I'm using onChartScale, however, I noticed your function uses the ViewPort width to calculate label sizes, is there any way to modify it to use the columns on screen? Since once the user zooms it doesn't consider this?

Comment: Do you want a flexible labelCount when scale is changed ?
 Try
 ```mAxis.getLabelCount()```

Comment: After reading source code in library, you can use
```mXAxis.mEntryCount```

It's more precise than getting label count from xAxis